# What is GQLAlchemy and which graph databases does it support?

Tags: python, graph-databases, memgraphdb

What is GQLAlchemy and is it limited only to Memgraph or can it be used with other graph databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GQLAlchemy](https://memgraph.com/gqlalchemy/) is a fully open-source Python library that aims to be the go-to Object Graph Mapper (OGM) -- a link between Graph Database objects and Python objects. GQLAlchemy supports Memgraph and Neo4j.

An Object Graph Mapper or OGM provides a developer-friendly workflow that allows for writing object-oriented notation to communicate to a graph database. Instead of writing Cypher queries, you will be able to write object-oriented code, which the OGM will automatically translate into Cypher queries.

Some of the GQLAlchemy features are:

- OGM Serialization and deserialization
- Automatic schema validation
- On-disk storage
- Custom data loaders
- Query builder
- Manage streams
- Manage database triggers
- Manage Memgraph instances

As said, GQLAlchemy supports Memgraph and Neo4j but on-disk storage feature only works with Memgraph. Neo4j is not supported.